# Flutter Alarm Application Permissions

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, alarm, lockscreen

I am developing a flutter alarm application and I ran into a problem. Probably it is easy to solve, but as I do not know how I thought you might know. I attached a file showing the other permissions feed of the alarm application alarmy which I found in the playstore. In the file, you can see that the "Show on Lock screen" and the "Display pop-up windows while running in the background" permission are both accepted from the start. On the other hand in case of the alarm application "Ultra Alarm" I am developing the two permission are denied from the start and I do not know how to change that. Maybe you can help me. It is a mi device.
[image: other permissions feed of alarmy]

[image: other permissions feed of my app]

Comment: can you please share the permissions you have asked for in android manifest file it will helpful to give answer and please tell me have you asked user for permissions in app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's disabled by the system or if you haven't asked for the permissions, in the second case I recommend you to use [permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler), on the other hand, if the system is blocking the app to grant the permission it's becasuse you haven't made the setup on your Info.plist
I recommend you to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646085/how-to-request-and-check-permissions-in-flutter)

Comment: In the beginning, I thought I would have to ask for the permissions but then I downloaded another alarm application and saw that even before opening the app for the first time the permissions I need were already accepted. So I thought maybe I need to add the relevant permission only to the main xml file and do not ask for it. As I did not know how the permissions were called I simply added all permissions that exist to my xml file and tested if the permissions I need are accepted then and they were not. Therefore now I am pretty confused.

Comment: @TheUltimateOptimist you also have to code in a flutter to check if the permission is accepted or not. generally, it would ask you for permission if you create an alarm. if the permission is not accepted then the developer has to use the premission_handler plugin available on the pub. dev. to ensure users add this premission.